# Alternative to INDIRECT in ARRAYFORMULA to reference the cell above

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to achieve nested conditions in Google Sheets.
3 columns test to see if a condition exists (find the word "nulled" across other columns).  They're called into action by their number (1,2,3).  If the column is already handling a conditional level, then it does not perform the test but copies the cell above to continue the decision (using INDIRECT). They're summarised in the final column, again, looking across the row to see if annulled or not.

[image]

I have a working formula but it won't sit within ARRAYFORMULA because it uses INDIRECT to reference the cell content above.
I desperately want to put it into ARRAYFORMULA as the current formula has to be copied to every cell.

```js
=
if ($E: $E < $1: $1, "<",
  if ($E: $E > $1: $1, indirect("R[-1]C[0]", false),
    if (and($E: $E = $1: $1, isblank($A: $D)), indirect("R[-1]C[0]", false),
      if (and($E: $E = $1: $1, not(isblank($A: $D))),
        if (or($A: $A = "nulled", $B: $B = "nulled", $C: $C = "nulled", $D: $D = "nulled"), "nulled", "active"),
        "-"))))
```

**INDIRECT doesn't sit within ARRAYFORMULA so is there an alternative way to achieve it?** (or any other feedback on how to do nested conditionals a better way...)

Comment: here's a link to the sheet. I've simplified it so only looking for the condition in one column:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1InMwXIUMivuCZ1Te-FzHTLak9xGn_KHbV3B8Gj12X9Q/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((E2:E=""),,IF(E2:E<F1:H1, "<",
 IF((E2:E>F1:H1)+((E2:E=F1:H1)*(ISBLANK(A2:D))), VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A),  
 IF(A2:A<>"", {row(A2:A), IFERROR(IF((E2:E=F1:H1)*(NOT(ISBLANK(A2:D))),
 IF((A2:A="nulled")+(B2:B="nulled")+
    (C2:C="nulled")+(D2:D="nulled"), "nulled", "active"), ))}), 2, 1),
 IF((E2:E=F1:H1)*(NOT(ISBLANK(A2:D))),
 IF((A2:A="nulled")+(B2:B="nulled")+
    (C2:C="nulled")+(D2:D="nulled"), "nulled", "active"), "-")))))
```

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((E2:E=""),,IF(E2:E<F1:H1, "<",
 IF((E2:E>F1:H1)+((E2:E=F1:H1)*(ISBLANK(A2:D))), VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A),  
 IF(INDEX(IFERROR(IF((E2:E=F1:H1)*(NOT(ISBLANK(A2:D))),
 IF((A2:A="nulled")+(B2:B="nulled")+
    (C2:C="nulled")+(D2:D="nulled"), "nulled", "active"), )),,1)<>"", 
 {ROW(A2:A), IFERROR(IF((E2:E=F1:H1)*(NOT(ISBLANK(A2:D))),
 IF((A2:A="nulled")+(B2:B="nulled")+
    (C2:C="nulled")+(D2:D="nulled"), "nulled", "active"), ))}), 2, 1),
 IF((E2:E=F1:H1)*(NOT(ISBLANK(A2:D))),
 IF((A2:A="nulled")+(B2:B="nulled")+
    (C2:C="nulled")+(D2:D="nulled"), "nulled", "active"), "-")))))
```

[image]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14EAXCakSKh8vRk5gSbp3vDuYSu8D1OFnQGMA57QIfQo/edit#gid=783035058)

Comment: Almost, and I apologize for conflating 2 issues.  Allow me to try to clarify:
- If the nLevel = column label, then test condition,
- if the nLevel > column label, then a nested condition is being tested so just copy down the result from the first.
(The summation of results are aggregated elsewhere for overall result)

Comment: did you try the formula? isn't this the output you need?

Comment: Nope, as the results need to copy down the columns. While the nLevel is above the one being tested, the cell needs to copy the value in the cell above. Hence the INDIRECT function to reference the cell above.

Comment: can you make the sheet commentable so i can point something out on it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the dragdown formula you built is "itereative".  That is, it uses the previous answer as a part of it's output for every given cell.

This is largely not possible with Arrayformula with a few exceptions involving cumulative summing/subtracting that can be done with a sort of trick.

It's possible there's another way to do what you're trying to do, but i'm not sure i understand the example well enough to think outside the box of what's been presented.  Could you share a little more detail about what is really going on in the sheet?

Comment: Hi - thanks for your attention.
You're right - it is reiterative. I know this can be enabled in the gSheet but I'd rather not (there's already a load of calcs occurring in the sheets),
I'm trying this as method for nested conditionals, using a sequence of rows to accumulate "nulled" conditions.
- If none of the conditions are anulled then the set is valid.
- If any of the conditions are anulled then the following conditions are also anulled from that point.
So each new condition brings the result from the previous row in the former columns.

Comment: Aha! Excellent, then I believe it can be done with an mmult. But to help I would need to see the underlying data and conditional formulas that create the nulls. Can you share something more complete in your shared sheet?

Comment: i've put a more expansive example into the sheet ('MattKing'). I hope it's still understandable. It illustrates how multiple sets are tested, running down the rows. The current formula (per cell) are present in the sheet. I've not looked into MMULT before so looking forward to seeing this in action!

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for sharing that.  are the nLevels coming from a formula on the real sheet?  It seems you are trying to basically give a designation for whether a particular row is a subset of another row above it.  So it's like a parent- child-grandchild designation?
If so, what is the formula you're using to determine it, or are you doing it manually?

Comment: bingo :) all you say above. To andser your question on nLevel - i put those in as raw values manually to designate parent-child relationships.